# Python operation data List in loop

Tags: python, list, loops, sum, conditional-statements

I want to solve my programming problem, the problem goes like so:

```
input: 3 #if i input as first input example 3, output is [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3] 
input: 2  #2nd input example 2 output is [1, 2] + [1, 2, 3] = [2, 4, 6]
[2, 4, 3]
input: 6 #3rd input [2, 4, 6] + [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] = [3, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6]
```

My code:

```
while True:
    a = input('Input : ')
    n = range (1,a+1,1)

    print n
```

Outputs:

```
 Input : 3
 [1, 2, 3]
 Input : 2
 [1, 2]
 Input : 6
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Look up a little more about what the `range` command does.  You're close, but you're modifying the wrong parts of the range based on a.

Comment: Hayy Idos. I  have problem at operation data list,, i can not sum list 1 to list 2.. can you give me solution??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but i can not use external code

Then you can write some code that does exactly what `izip_longest` does with the zero padding when the new entry is lengthier than the previous result.

The sums are performed in a *list comprehension* where the values and indices from the input list are gotten by applying `enumerate` on the entry in the comprehension. Values from the accumulated list are indexed and added to new values at the same index:

```
tot = []
while True:
    a = input('Input : ')
    n = range (1,a+1,1)
    x, y = len(tot), len(n)
    if y > x:
        tot[x:y] = [0]*(y-x) # pad the tot list with zeros
    tot[:y] = [tot[i]+v for i, v in enumerate(n)]
    print tot
```

Output:

```
Input : 3
[1, 2, 3]
Input : 2
[2, 4, 3]
Input : 6
[3, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6]
Input : 1
[4, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6]
Input : 0
[4, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Your answer  is work but i dont understand this code [tot[i]+v for i, v in enumerate(n)]

Comment: Can you tell me about that

Answer (score 3):

Building on your existing code, I would use [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) (Python 2, for 3 use `zip.longest`):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> nxt = []
>>> while True:
    a = input('Input : ')
    n = range(1, a+1, 1) # could change to range(1, a+1)
    nxt = map(sum, itertools.izip_longest(n, nxt, fillvalue=0))

    print nxt
```

Which yields:

```
Input : 3
[1, 2, 3]
Input : 2
[2, 4, 3]
Input : 6
[3, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Hay Idos.. Thank you very much... but i can not use external code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use map

```
result = []
while True:
    a = input('Input : ')
    n = range(1, a+1)
    result = [(x or 0) + (y or 0) for x,y in map(None, n, result)]
    print result
```

and result would be:

```
Input : 3
[1, 2, 3]
Input : 2
[2, 4, 3]
Input : 6
[3, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: hai.. Taxellool .. thanks for your answer, but i can not solve my problem with your answer

Comment: why? whats your problem with this?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "haha.py", line 4, in <module>
            result = [(x or 0) + (y or 0) for x,y in map(None, n, result)]
        NameError: name 'result' is not defined

Comment: It is defined.. look at the first line `result = []`

Comment: you forgot to add the first line. you did not define result.
add "result = []" before your loop as shown in answer and it works.

Comment: But i won't to use map.. i want solve this problem with conditional and looping but don't worry i ll check your answer if i get solution.. and you know this is quiz from training class and i not yet get map materi